# Unable to read SObject's field value[s] in lightning component while upserting data

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I am developing a lightning component in lightning enabled sandbox(Summer'16) while insert/upsert i am facing a issue it says ('**Unable to read SObject's field value[s]**'), The same code is working in Developer sandbox(Spring'16 for developers).

Here is my code:
**Component file**:

```
<aura:attribute name="pollQuestionObj" type="Polling_Question__c" default="{'sobjectType': 'Polling_Question__c'}"/>
```

**Controller file**:

```
 ({

        //Add Polling Questions.
        addQuestion : function(component, event, helper) {
            var pollQuest = component.get("v.pollQuestionObj"); 

            var visibleTo = component.find("visTo").get("v.value");

            helper.addPollQuestions(component, pollQuest,visibleTo, function(a){
                console.log('Question Added');            
            });
      },

        //Get Selected Option Value.    
        onSelectChange : function(component, event, helper) {
             var selectedItem = component.get("v.pollOptions");
             helper.OnSelectChange(component, selectedItem, function(a){
                console.log('Item Selected'); 

            });
       }
})
```

**Helper file**:

```
  ({
     //Add Polling Questions.
    addPollQuestions : function(component,pollQuest,visibleToItem,callback) {
     debugger;   

    var questOptions = component.find("options").get("v.value");        

    var pollQuestion = component.find("question");
    var questValue = pollQuestion.get("v.value");

    var optionVal = component.find();

    //Check if question is entered.
    if(questValue == undefined)
    {
        alert('Please enter question');
        /*var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title": "Required!",
                    "message": "Please enter question."
                });                    
         toastEvent.fire();*/
         return false;
    }

    var optionValList = [];

    for (i = 1; i <= questOptions; i++) {
        var optionVal = $('#option' + i).val()
        if( optionVal != "" &&  optionVal != undefined)
        {
            optionVal = optionVal; 
            optionValList.push(optionVal);                
        }
        else{
            alert("Please enter all number of options as selected");
            /*var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            toastEvent.setParams({
                "title": "Required!",
                "message": "Please enter all number of options as selected."
            });                    
            toastEvent.fire();
            */
            return false;
        }

    } 
    //alert('Option Value List: ' + optionValList);
    /*if(optionValList == undefined && optionValList.length < 2)
    {
        alert("Please enter atleast 2 options");
        return false;
    }*/

    var action = component.get("c.addPollQuestion"); // name on the apex class function
    //var pollQuest=component.get("v.pollQuestionObj");
    // set the sobjectType!
    pollQuest.sobjectType='Polling_Question__c';
    action.setParams({"pollQuest": pollQuest,"visibleToItem":visibleToItem,"optionValList":optionValList});    

    //Get callback.
    if(callback)
    {

        // Create a callback that is executed after the server-side action returns
          action.setCallback(this, function(response) {

            //Get response state.
            var state = response.getState();

            //Check if response is success.
            if (state === "SUCCESS") { 
                 alert("Poll Question saved successfully");
                 //component.set("v.message", response.getReturnValue());
                /*var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title": "Success!",
                    "message": "Poll Question saved successfully."
                });                    
                toastEvent.fire();*/

            }
            else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {    
               alert("INCOMPLETE");    
               //component.set("v.message", response.getReturnValue());
            }    
            //Check for error.
            else if (state === "ERROR") {    

                var errors = response.getError();    
                if (errors) {    
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) { 
                        alert("Error message: " +errors[0].message);
                        //component.set("v.message", errors[0].message);
                        //System.debug(errors[0].message);
                        /*var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                        toastEvent.setParams({
                            "title": "Error!",
                            "message": "Unable to submit data. Please contact your system admin"
                        });                    
                        toastEvent.fire();*/
                    }
                } else {                        
                    alert("Unknown error");                                                                                       
                }    
            }
            }); 

    }
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  },

    //Get Selected Option Value.
OnSelectChange: function(component, event, helper){
    //var selected = component.find("options").get("v.item");

    var resultCmp = component.find("options").get("v.value");
    //resultCmp.set("v.pollOptions", options.get("v.value"));
    console.log(resultCmp);
                            //alert(resultCmp);   
                            //Empty main div of option group.   
    $("#OptionGroup").empty();
    //Iterate number of option and create option textbox.
    for (i = 1; i <= resultCmp; i++) { 
                            var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
                    .attr("id", 'OptionDiv' + i);                
                                            newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Option #'+ i + ' : </label>' +
        '<input type="text" name="option' + i + 
        '" id="option' + i + '" value="" >');            
                                            newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#OptionGroup");
                            }

    //alert(resultCmp);
}


})
```

Comment: did you check field level security  of that field ?

Comment: @erkan Yes, i checked it.

Comment: I''m having same kind of error in Summer 16 pre-release org. Have you found cause if this error or any resolution?

Answer (score 8):

I just solve the same error message it was due to a date format.

```
   var  mydate = new Date(contact.Birthdate);
    contact.Birthdate = mydate ;
```

Comment: 4 years later, this has helped me

Comment: for people reading this later, In case you load an existing record in Lightning cmp (having date field in the form, `ui:inputDate` in my case), this issue happens when date field is set to some date & the user attempts to save. 
This small change resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Unable to read SObject's field value[s]** error occur when we send the wrong type value for the fields **or** not sending the sobjectType in the object param.

**Example :** sending text value for number type field

Answer (score 0):

I converted the date to an ISO string:

```
var varStartDateTime = new Date();
newEvent.StartDateTime = varStartDateTime.toISOString();
```