# Lightning: Passing Date in format [YYYY-M-D] gives error "Unable to read SObject's field value[s]"

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps, error, platform-bug

Passing Date in format [YYYY-M-D] like "2016-1-1" gives error "Unable to read SObject's field value[s]"

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create custom object Custom_Object__c with Date field Date__c
2. Create Apex Class

   ```
   public class DateIssueCont {
   @AuraEnabled
   public static void saveRecord( Custom_Object__c rec ){
       insert rec;
   }
   }
   ```
3. Create an App

   ```
   <aura:application controller="DateIssueCont">    
   <aura:attribute name="record" type="Custom_Object__c" default="{'sobjectType': 'Custom_Object__c', 'Date__c': ''}" />
   <ui:inputDate value="{!v.record.Date__c}" displayDatePicker="true" /> 
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
   <div aura:id="errors" class="slds-hide">
       <div class="slds-form-element" >
           <div class="slds-form-element__control">
               <ui:message title="Error" severity="error" >
                   <ui:outputText aura:id="ErrorMessage" value=""/>
               </ui:message>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.perform}">Perform Business Logic</button>
   </aura:application>
   ```
4. With Javascript Controller

   ```
   ({
   init : function(component, event, helper) {
       component.set("v.record.Date__c", '2016-1-1' );
   },

   perform : function(component, event, helper) {
       var rec = component.get( 'v.record' );
       var saveRecord = component.get( "c.saveRecord" );
       saveRecord.setParam( "rec", rec ); 
       saveRecord.setCallback(this, function(response) {
           var state = response.getState();
           if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
           } else if (state === "ERROR"){
               var errors = response.getError();
               if (errors && errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                   $A.util.removeClass( component.find("errors"), "slds-hide");
                   component.find("ErrorMessage").set("v.value", errors[0].message);
               }
               if (errors && errors[0] && errors[0].pageErrors && errors[0].pageErrors[0] && errors[0].pageErrors[0].message ) {
                   $A.util.removeClass( component.find("errors"), "slds-hide");
                   component.find("ErrorMessage").set("v.value", errors[0].pageErrors[0].message);
               }
               if (errors && errors[0] && errors[0].fieldErrors  ) {
                   $A.util.removeClass( component.find("errors"), "slds-hide");
                   for ( var u in errors[0].fieldErrors) {
                       component.find("ErrorMessage").set("v.value", errors[0].fieldErrors[u][0].message);
                   } 

               }
           }
       });
       $A.enqueueAction(saveRecord);
   }
   })
   ```

   5. Open an app and click button.
   6. Obtain an error which says "Unable to read SObject's field value[s]".

[image: Error: Unable to read SObject's field value[s]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several workarounds for this issue.

1. The most simple in this case is to use YYYY-MM-DD.

So we would have to change line

```
component.set("v.record.Date__c", '2016-1-1' );
```

into

```
component.set("v.record.Date__c", '2016-01-01' );
```

2. Another possible workaround is mentioned [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121986/unable-to-read-sobjects-field-values-in-lightning-component-while-upserting-d):

We could add line

```
rec.Date__c = new Date( rec.Date__c );
```

just after

```
var rec = component.get( 'v.record' );
```

line in perform method of javascript controller.

3. Another general workaround for a custom date population was described [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/123053/unable-to-save-record-with-on-load-initialized-date-field-in-lightning-component).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try by using Date format instead of string ?

```
component.set("v.record.Date__c", new Date('2016-1-1') );
```

Comment: yes, I have mentioned that below